# Best RAID Solution for dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, raid-1

I've seen this topic talked about before on this site but with other users using 2 drives for the active partition (booting from the same HDD thats got RAID) however my situation is a bit different.

This is how I want to set up my drives:

[image: Drive Config]

I want to be able to access the Data drive from both the Windows and Ubuntu OS while maintaining RAID 1, I heard this can accomplished with FakeRAID, I was wondering if someone could confirm this or recommend the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to use a RAID card or integrated RAID on a motherboard.  It can be integrated RAID into your motherboard, a "fake" RAID card or dedicated hardware RAID card. You cannot use pure software raid with the setup you described.

So first you simply setup your RAID arrays per your RAID documentation; this will be done before your OS boots.  Then, on each OS, install the appropriate RAID driver, if needed, to read the array.  That is it.  Each OS will see the array and be able to mount it as a drive.